# Method undefined for type HttpServlet error in Java

Tags: java, servlets

I am getting the above message when I use respond with a method and I don't have any clues on how to fix it, I have java servlet 3.1 which seems to be the only answer I can find elsewhere that could resolve it.

```
import java.io.*;
import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.http.*;
import java.sql.*;

public class login extends HttpServlet {

protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServlet response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();

    String username = request.getParameter("username");
    String password = request.getParameter("password");

    if(Validate.checkUser(username, password))
    {
        RequestDispatcher rs = request.getRequestDispatcher("Welcome");
        rs.forward(request, response);
    }
    else
    {
        out.println("Username or Password incorrect");
        RequestDispatcher rs = request.getRequestDispatcher("login.html");
        rs.include(request, response);
    }
}

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

check you post method 
[HttpServlet](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/1.3/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServlet.html#doPost%28javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,%20javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse%29) has doPost method which accepts HttpServleRequest and HttpServletResponse arguments

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServlet response) throws ServletException, IOException {
```

to

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws     ServletException, IOException {
```